# Does Gmail limit receiving multiple nearly-identical messages into the same account?

Tags: gmail

I am sending a large number (over 70 within 1-2 minutes) emails with identical subject and content to the same Gmail account from a third-party email server.  Address is formatted as 'gmailusername+person.name@gmail.com', where 'gmailusername' is the same for all messages, and 'person.name' is different for every message.

The first 3 messages arrived normally, but the rest seem to have disappeared.

Is where a Gmail limitation on recieving multiple nearly identical messages?  Where can I find info on it?

The email content is a few lines of plain text.  The account is used for testing, in production setting these emails will go to different addresses.  These 70+ emails to the same address are the only emails that are being sent by the server at the time, i.e. there is not much other activity sending email from the same server to other Gmail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Gmail limit emails, yes.  But since you're testing, can you just change the subject with a time stamp, number, or guid?  That might help.

```
"Testing Message 1", "Testing Message 2", etc.
```

Edit:

You won't run into limiting problems if you can either a) setup your own relay (very hard, but refer to [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) for a little help) or b) use an email campaign service provider such as [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) or [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/). Note that it's good to be educated on the difference between "transactional" email and normal, bulk-advertising email.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it's not a limit that's stopping you, it's their anti-spam filters; if their servers receive many identical e-mails differing only be recipient within a short space of time from a single sender, they'll often or not block them, obviously there are some algorithms going on behind the scenes to establish if it is actually spam (i.e. is the sender server part of a known spam network, is the sender on the trusted senders list of the recipients etc.) although we'll know exactly what goes in to deciding if the e-mail should be considered spam or not. ;)

You'll find most of the popular e-mail providers (Yahoo, Gmail etc.) do this.

Most mailing list providers get around this by automatically fragmenting how many e-mails are sent to a single provider in an hour - not to mention the bigger mailing providers are often or not more trusted by the e-mail providers that their content is legitimate.

While I think you're in the sending limit, do be aware Google will disable your account for 24 hours if they believe you are spamming. More information [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839).

Comment: The messages all go to the same Gmail account, so technically it's the same recipient.  Sender is trusted by the recipient, and it's not on any spam sender list.

Comment: @jprusakova Okay, I understand - my apologies, I took the 
>>Address is formatted as 'gmailusername+person.name@gmail.com'
to mean different recipients.